# Date format issue in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, date, date-format

I am trying to parse a date from a textbox and store it in a date variable

```
Dim enddt_2 As Date = Date.ParseExact(txtenddt.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)  'txtenddt.Text
expenddt_1 = enddt_2.AddDays(-1)
enddt = enddt_2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

`enddt` is a Date variable and when i convert `enddt_2` to a string i get the error as

```
Conversion from string "17/01/2012" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Let me clarify, if a value in textbox is **17/01/2012** than after parsing the value is changed to **01/17/2012** (*my systems Region and Language are dd/MM/yyyy*) in `enddt_2` and when i try to convert to **dd/MM/yyyy** format and store into a date variable i get the above error. This error comes only for the dates after 12. i.e a date variable accepts a date in MM/dd/yyyy format.The dates before 12 work fine, i.e for all dates from 1 to 12 there is no error.

How can i make `enddt` store the date in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enddt` is `Date` variable and you can't assign string value in it and do not change your regional settings or even date/time format.

Change type of `enddt` if you want to store string date.

```
 Dim enddt as String = enddt_2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I want it to be date variable, as i need to used these date variable later in the code

Comment: @Ishan - If you customize your regional settings then you do not have to convert. Just check  MsgBox(Date.Now.Today) and MsgBox(enddt_2.ToDay)

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
Dim enddt_2 As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("17/01/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", _
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim newD As Date = enddt_2.AddDays(-1)

Dim xStr As String = "Original Date: " & enddt_2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & vbCrLf
xStr &= "FormatedOriginalDate: " & enddt_2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & vbCrLf
xStr &= "NewDate: " & newD.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
Console.Writeline(xStr)
```

Output:

```
Original Date:         17/01/2012
FormatedOriginalDate:  01/17/2012
NewDate:               01/16/2012
```